# Chatbot with Microsoft Office365/outlook Calendar

Tags: botframework, microsoft-graph-api, chatbot, office365api, office365-apps

I want to  develop a chatbot and want to integrate Microsoft Office365/Outlook calendar.
So flow of application will be like this:

1) From Admin panel  Manager user will invite Partner users and partner users will come and connect to their office 365 calendar and and enable access to share it. Now this calendar will be available for chatbot.

2) on FrontEnd(chatbot) guest or registered users will provide their emails and book meeting from the available timing based on calendar.
.. guest users will provide there emails and get the available timing from a partner user calendar.

I started looking at Microsoft Graph API. 
Can someone provide me with a good start?

Answer (score 1):

To do this you will have to use the authentication features in bot framework.  There is a good [walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) to get you started.  There is also a [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/24.bot-authentication-msgraph) that demonstrates the use of the [MS Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph).

Comment: Thanks, So how we will allow to see the Meeting timings and to book meetings by guest users. Like I will connect to my outlook calander now other guest users book meeting according to free times. how guest users will see my calander free times? how authentication will work here?

Comment: Have the users been added to your tenant and AAD as guests?

Comment: no. the flow will look like that I will allow app to access my calander. Now I will create a chat bot app to access that calander so anyone can join that chat and access calander to see free/busy on calander and can book meetings

Comment: I'm not sure how you would do that then, sorry.  You would have to expose the calendar some way.  I just do not have experience setting something like that up.